# Store a specific table to another file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a huge database and my search has been very slow.

In my database has a `File` table that I like to store to another ndf file?

Anyone ever done this?

Please help me

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: What should I do for split my table to Two file?

Comment: @marc_s Another .mdf file **<>** another SQL server database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention the database engine, so here is an example for MSSQL:

Create a new filegroup:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase ADD FILEGROUP FG_FilegroupName;
```

After that add a new file to the filegroup

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase ADD FILE (
    NAME = FILE_LogicalName,
    FILENAME = 'Path\To\Data\File.ndf',
    SIZE = 54MB, -- This is the initial size of the file. If you can estimate the size of the file after moving your table, adjust this value to that value.
)
```

The next step is to drop the clustered index on the table (if exists), then create a new one on the new filegroup you created:

```
ALTER TABLE YourDatabase.schema.TableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SchemaName_TableName PRIMARY CLUSTERED (ColumnNames)
        ON [FG_FilegroupName]
```

Comment: Thats true, but the question was: Store a specific table to another MDF file in SQL Server?

Comment: You got what I want. Thank u so much.